# Surly Trucker Disc Compatibility with Ryde Taurus Rims

Tags: frames, rims, compatibility

Is it possible to put these Rims ([Ryde Taurus 21 Disc: 26', 21-559](https://www.ridewill.it/p/en/ryde-2042635200-rim-ryde-taurus-disc-26-black-32-hole-aluminum/120086/)) on this frame ([Surly Trucker Disc](https://surlybikes.com/bikes/disc_trucker/frame_highlights))? I just cannot find any hint at the Surly Trucker description, but since I am not a native and new to bikes I might have missed something.

By the way, I want to use a Shutter Precision PD-8 hub but I think if the Ryde Taurus fits and I know the Shutter fits into the Ryde I can use it as long as the Ryde Taurus can be used.

Comment: You can also ask Surly support if you have doubts.

Comment: Please see my edit on frame sizes vs wheel sizes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** the wheel size for this bike model depends on the frame size!

- 26˝ wheels for frames 42, 46, 50–62 cm
- 700c (a.k.a. 28") wheels for frames 56–64 cm

So you need first to make sure that your bike runs wheel size 26", as Ryde Taurus rims are 26".

Having smaller wheels on a frame designed for bigger wheels is possible for disk brake systems, but it is not recommended unless you are certain (i.e. you have already tried it) you will be fine with changed (worsened) bike handling.

---

The same web [page](https://surlybikes.com/bikes/disc_trucker/bike_specs), "Complete bike parts kit" tab lists both 29" and 26" wheels as options, depending on frame size:

- Tires (26˝) Continental Tour Ride, 26 x 1.75"
- Tires (700c) Continental Contact, 700c x 37mm

The rims you mention have 19 mm inner width:

[image]

These rims should be compatible with the original 26" × 1.75" tires.

Note that you asked about frame vs wheel rims compatibility. You also mention hubs that you want to use; frame/hub, fork/hub and hub/rim compatibility issues are different question. In particular, the chosen rim should have the same number of spoke holes as the hub has, and that hub comes with hole counts varying from 28 to 36.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers dealt very well with the rim diameter compatibility depending on the the frame size.

Once you have figured out what rim diameter you require, you need to pick a rim width. That is based on what width tire you want. Quoting from the Surly web page

> 26": 2.1" with or without fenders; 700c: 42mm with fenders, 45mm without fenders

(Weird mix of inch and mm measurements but oh well ..)

You can run a quite wide tire in there. If you want to run tires in the 35-42mm range you should consider slightly wider rim than 19mm. If you search this site (or just google) you can find links to tire/rim size guides.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Perfect, I gonna take the Taurus 21 rim.